# Writing specs for Atom editor

Tags: coffeescript, specifications, atom-editor

I'm trying to write a simple package for Atom.io editor. This is my first experience with Coffeescript. 
So I'm probably missing something trivial.

Anyway, this is my index.coffee

```
module.exports =
 activate: ->
   atom.workspaceView.command "md-utils:unorderedList", => @unorderedList()
 unorderedList: ->
   out = ""
   editor = atom.workspace.activePaneItem
   selection = editor.getSelection()
   lines = selection.getText().split "\n"
   for line in lines
   out += "- " + line + "\n"
   console.log(lines)
   selection.insertText(out)
```

And here it is my index-spec.coffee

```
{WorkspaceView} = require 'atom'

    describe "Markdown Utilities", ->
      [editor, editorView] = []

      unorderedList = (callback) ->
        editorView.trigger "md-utils:unorderedList"
        runs(callback)


      beforeEach ->

        atom.workspaceView = new WorkspaceView
        atom.workspaceView.openSync()

        editorView = atom.workspaceView.getActiveView()
        editor = editorView.getEditor()

      describe "when text is selected", ->
        it "formats it correctly", ->
          console.log = jasmine.createSpy("log")
          editor.setText """
            a
            b
            c
            d
          """
          editor.selectAll()
          unorderedList ->
            expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalled()
            expect(editor.getText()).toBe """
            - a
            - b
            - c
            - d
          """
```

Now, when I run the spec looks like the method in the index.coffee is not even called.
Both expectations failed :

- *Expected spy log to have been called.*
- *Expected 'a b c d' to be '-a -b -c -d"*

The method in itself works , so I do not understand why test fails. 
Any suggestion is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your specs lack of a package activation, which is generally done with something like this:

```
beforeEach ->

  atom.workspaceView = new WorkspaceView
  atom.workspaceView.openSync()

  editorView = atom.workspaceView.getActiveView()
  editor = editorView.getEditor()

  # Package activation is done within a promise so this will wait for the end of it
  # before actually running the tests.
  waitsForPromise -> atom.packages.activatePackage('your-package-name')
```

As your package is never activated, the command you define in the `activate` method is never registered, so the event triggered in your `unorderedList` helper never reach it.